# Screen capture with scrolling, capturing drop-downs, cursor and tooltips

Tags: windows, gratis, screenshot

I am looking for a ***gratis***  and ***free for commercial use*** Windows screen capture program.

At home, I have always used the [last free version of FastStone screen capture](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=775) (here's [an alternative link](http://forum.videohelp.com/images/guides/p1960914/fscapture.zip) for those behind corporate fire walls which don't like the first link), but am in anew job and it is not permitted to use it in a commercial environment, so I am looking for an alternative, so that I can use the same program at home and work.

So far, I have tried only GreenShot, which people praise, but which does not impress me for reasons given below.

**Must Have**

- permision to use it in a commercial environment
- user configurable delay timer for capture
- cropping
- the ability to capture scrolling windows
- and browser Windows (GreenShot capture a black rectangle)
- and the cursor
- and drop down combo boxes as part of the window (GreenShot captures these separately)
- and tooltips
- a built in annotation editor

  - draw a rectangle
  - a text box
  - lines & arrows

**Nice to have**
 - auto numbering, like Greenshot

Any other bells & whistles are welcome

Comment: To capture a complete web page, you can use firefox browser's inbuilt tool to capture screnshot.

Press Shift + F2 -> "screenshot --fullpage" then hit enter. Full webpage screenshot will be saved to Downloads folder in your PC.

Comment: I'd recommend [Ashampoo Snap](https://www.ashampoo.com/en/usd/pin/1224/multimedia-software/snap-8), but it's not free (there's only a trial) :(

Comment: I can't believe that no one else takes screenshots at work :-(

Comment: I would suggest a newer version of GreenShot - it has many improvements and the browser window issue is probably fixed.

Comment: I found something even better than GreenShot - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) is a free and open source program
>   that lets you capture or record any area of your screen and share it
>   with a single press of a key. It also allows uploading images, text or
>   other types of files to over 80 supported destinations you can choose
>   from.

The features are simply too many to describe, - check them for yourself - suffice it to say that my search is over.

Comment: Does not capture browser tooltip popup, but does capture cursor.